# flutter dart splash screen

Tags: flutter, dart, splash-screen

I'm trying to place the splash screen and I get the following error:

If the home property is specified, the routes table cannot include an entry for "/", since it would be redundant.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/app.dart':

Main.dart

```
 import 'splashscreen.dart';
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        assert(() {
          debugPaintSizeEnabled = _configuration.debugShowSizes;
          debugPaintBaselinesEnabled = _configuration.debugShowBaselines;
          debugPaintLayerBordersEnabled = _configuration.debugShowLayers;
          debugPaintPointersEnabled = _configuration.debugShowPointers;
          debugRepaintRainbowEnabled = _configuration.debugShowRainbow;
          return true;
        }());
        return MaterialApp(
          home: new SplashPage(),
          title: 'Program',
          theme: theme,
          localizationsDelegates: SStrings.localizationsDelegates,
          supportedLocales: SStrings.supportedLocales,
          debugShowMaterialGrid: _configuration.debugShowGrid,
          showPerformanceOverlay: _configuration.showPerformanceOverlay,
          showSemanticsDebugger: _configuration.showSemanticsDebugger,
          routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
             '/':         (BuildContext context) => SHome(s, _configuration, configurationUpdater),
             '/settings': (BuildContext context) => SSettings(_configuration, configurationUpdater),
          },
          onGenerateRoute: _getRoute,
        );
      }
    }
```

SplashScreen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class SplashPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SplashPageState createState() => SplashPageState();
}

class SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> {
  void navigationToNextPage() {
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 's');
  }

  startSplashScreenTimer() async {
    var _duration = new Duration(seconds: 5);
    return new Timer(_duration, navigationToNextPage);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startSplashScreenTimer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);

    return Container(
        child: new Image.asset('assets/logo.png'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using named routes, you don't specify home you use **initialRoute** instead.

And since you want your splash screen to show up first, its route name has to be the initial route

Try this.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  assert(() {
    debugPaintSizeEnabled = _configuration.debugShowSizes;
    debugPaintBaselinesEnabled = _configuration.debugShowBaselines;
    debugPaintLayerBordersEnabled = _configuration.debugShowLayers;
    debugPaintPointersEnabled = _configuration.debugShowPointers;
    debugRepaintRainbowEnabled = _configuration.debugShowRainbow;
    return true;
  }());
  return MaterialApp(
    initialRoute: '/',
    title: 'Program',
    theme: theme,
    localizationsDelegates: SgpStrings.localizationsDelegates,
    supportedLocales: SgpStrings.supportedLocales,
    debugShowMaterialGrid: _configuration.debugShowGrid,
    showPerformanceOverlay: _configuration.showPerformanceOverlay,
    showSemanticsDebugger: _configuration.showSemanticsDebugger,
    routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
      '/' :(BuildContext context) => SplashSpage(),
      '/shome':         (BuildContext context) => SHome(s, _configuration, configurationUpdater),
      '/settings': (BuildContext context) => SgpSettings(_configuration, configurationUpdater),
    },
    onGenerateRoute: _getRoute,
  );
}
```

Note that the route name for your Home has changed and you should use **/shome** (or you can change it) and time you want to go **SHome**

Comment: so good, the splash screen appeared but in the home, data that was loaded did not appear. The previous way I call

Comment: What data? can you add your home?

Comment: Also `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/shome);` is to be used in the splash screen to prevent the phone back button from going back to splash screen.